# Filter Entries by Field Value

Tags: entries, search, filtering

How do I filter a list of entries by the value of a field? For example, if I have a lightswitch field called "Featured", how do I output just the featured entries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [search parameter](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching) in the `craft.entries` model:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('Blog').search('featuredFieldName:1') %}

    {# Entry Code #}

{% endfor %}
```

To filter by a specific text snippet:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('Blog').search('entryColor:"green"') %}

    {# Entry Code #}

{% endfor %}
```

You can create more complex search queries as well, see the documentation for more info. But the basic idea is to use `.search()`, then enter your search query in quotes.

Comment: While the `search` query param _will_ work for many field values, it ultimately gets parsed back into an explicit `ElementQuery`. The recommended way to filter by custom field data (or built-in Element properties) is to use the chaining syntax demonstrated in other answers; in addition to allowing for a wider variety of filtering strategies, it tends to be much easier to distinguish syntax issues (Twig and Search) from search index issues.

Answer (score 12):

Filtering a list of entries is quite simple. Here's an example from one of our sites:

```
{% for job in craft.entries({
    section: 'jobs',
    applicationsClose: ">= " ~ (now|date('Y-m-d')),
    internalExternal: 'external',
}) %}

    ...

{% endfor %}
```

Here we define the section we're looking in and then filter by two custom fields: `applicationsClose` and `internalExternal`.

Comment: Should be the better answer since there is no searching involved.

Answer (score 8):

```
{% set featuredProducts = craft.entries
    .section('sectionName')
    .featured(true)
    .all() %}
```

Where `sectionName` is the name of your section;

`featured` is your featured field handle;

`true` is the value you want to query the lightswitch fields for.

Each field type in the Craft docs has an element query example, e.g. [lightswitch fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/lightswitch-fields.html#querying-elements-with-lightswitch-fields)

Answer (score 3):

Another way for Craft 3

```
{# Create an entry query with the 'section' and 'limit' parameters #}
{% set entryQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('Blog')
    .search('entryColor:green')
    .limit(10) %}
                
{# Fetch the entries. #}
{% set entries = entryQuery.all() %}

{% if entries|length > 0 %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```