# Filtering values from Twig for my custom field type

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

I have a custom fieldtype for Craft which stores its value as an array of Models using AttributeType::Mixed. See below for an example of the FieldType and Model setup

```
class MyCustomFieldType extends BaseFieldType
{
    public function defineContentAttribute()
    {
        return AttributeType::Mixed;
    }
} 

class MyCustomModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'url'      => AttributeType::String,
            'category' => AttributeType::String
        );
    } 
}
```

Then when the value is persisted, it's saved as an array, which Craft natively saves as JSON

```
$values = [new MyCustomModel(), new MyCustomModel(), ...];
```

To display the value in Twig I can do something like

```
{% for item in entry.myCustomField %}
    {{ item.category }}
{% endfor %}
```

My question is, how can I only display the elements in my field which have a specific attribute value? For example, if I wanted to display only those items with a category of main, where 'category' is an attribute on my model?

```
{% for item in entry.myCustomField.category('main') %}
    {{ item.category }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

[Filter Entries by Field Value](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/filter-entries-by-field-value)

Than it would be something like this I suppose (never used it myself):

```
{% for item in entry.myCustomField.search('category':'main') %}
    {{ item.category }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried that ( the syntax is 'category:main' rather than 'category' : 'main') but that only seems to work for ElementCriteriaModel instances. Not sure how I can achieve the same thing for a custom type?

Comment: A long shot here. But have you tried it without the search() function? Just entry.myCustomField('category:main'). I would find it weird that it would work differently with custom fields than it does when using default ones.